# Is fork repository deleted?

Tags: github, copy, clone, google-photos

If i save a copy of a video in Google Drive or Photos in my Google Account, and the official repository is deleted, for some copyright reason, my fork repository is deleted together?

and in the GitHub?

Comment: Why are you asking about videos and Google Photos? What do they have to do with programming?

Comment: because the life is programming. and because the other stack communities did not accept my question.

Comment: That's no reason to post off-topic questions. Yes, we have lots of rules here. But they exist for good reasons. Please make sure to only ask questions that are **on-topic** according to the [help/on-topic], one question per post, and to ask them as clearly as possible (see [ask]). Following the rules is one of the ways to ensure you get the most out of Stack Overflow. If your video and Google Photos questions have nothing to do with programming they don't belong here, period.

Comment: I'm going to say this part again since it's so important: It's **your** job to ask your question as clearly as possible. If we can't understand what you're asking we can't help you. One of the reasons for the comment section is so we can ask you questions to clarify what you need. That's what I was trying to do here—maybe you're trying to interact with some Google Photos API. If you are, great, but you need to _tell us_.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility) if a private repository is deleted its forks are also deleted, and if a public repository is deleted one of the forks is chosen to be the new parent repository.

If you save a copy of the code outside of the GitHub ecosystem, e.g. in Google Drive as you suggest, nothing will happen when the upstream repository is deleted. Depending on how the code is licensed you may no longer be *permitted* to use the code you've saved, but it won't magically disappear.

Comment: What does that mean? What is "removed by copyrights", and how is that different from "deleted for any other reason"? My answer already says that you might not legally be allowed to use the code you've saved somewhere else. I'm not sure that there's more to say about it.